# Meaning of sentences begining with "such is..."

Tags: meaning

I was reading a Cambridge English book and I ran into a sentence like this:

> "such is our dependence on fossil fuels and such is the volume of carbon dioxide already releases into the atmosphere..."

I was wondering what are the synonyms or alternatives for this "such is...."

I was also wondering its meaning.

Comment: 'Such is our dependence on fossil fuels that ...' = 'We rely so much on fossil fuels that ...'.

Comment: *Such is* works in two ways. After you talk about X, you refer to it as "such": Such is my opinion. Also, in a lofty fashion: Such is the life! Wow!

Comment: such or this/that. It is a relative pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Such* is an allomorph of *so* and is used in many of the same constructions. *Such* introduces predicate nouns and *so* introduces predicate adjectives

- *It's such a loss! It's so soft!* (intensifier use)
- *He's such a fool/so stupid that `S`* (*so/such...that `S`* construction)
- *Such a fool/So stupid is he that `S`* (inverted *so/such* construction)

The presenting example in the question is an example of the last type. Like many types of constituent, the *so/such* part of the *so/such...that* construction can be fronted, triggering Subject-Auxiliary inversion. The construction is the same -- it still needs a *that*-clause to connect the *so/such* -- and the meaning is the same -- syntactic transformations don't change meaning.

But moving some element to the beginning of the sentence tends to emphasize the fronted element, not surprisingly. And doing it twice in the original example is just parallel construction; they will both share the same (omitted) *that*-clause, and reinforce each other's emphasis.

By the way, this question is a good example of why we should require complete example sentences in questions, instead of random strings and amateur abbreviations.