# What are some pro-adjectives?

Tags: adjectives

What are some pro-adjectives?  That is, a [pro-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form) that can substitute (satisfy the [substitution test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)) with) an adjectival phrase?  A Google search brought up "such", but was otherwise unfruitful.  Are there any others?

Edit:  As pointed out in the comments, "so" is mentioned in the first Wikipedia link above, but I think that "so": (1) can also substitute for units larger than an adjectival phrase such as a clause (e.g. "if so"), defeating the purpose of the test, and, (2) when it substitutes for an adjective, it is limited to comparatives.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link mentions: *so* as in "It is less *so* than we had expected."

Comment: This is an interesting question. We don't normally use pro-forms to transform, for example, "That car was _fast_" to "That car was ___". Perhaps it's because adjectives add colour to nouns while pro-forms do the opposite, so using a pro-form in place of an adjective or adjectival phrase defeats the purpose of using an adjective at all. However, your suggestion of "so" or "such" might work in a context such as "That car was *fast*. It was *so* because the driver was being pursued."

Comment: [_So/Such ... that_ `S`](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/590888/15299) is a construction that requires a baseline clause. It's not really a pro-form; _so_ modifies predicate adjectives and _such_ predicate nouns. English pro-adjectives are usually phrases like _that way_.

Comment: "Such" fails your substitution test: "such a person" but not "smart a person."

Comment: @alphabet It actually passes if you don't consider word order to be part of the test. ("I need a smart person. She is **such** a person." -> "She is a **smart** person.") In any case, **such** a test (i.e., a **substitution** test) is really just an aid; OP probably overstated its usefulness in identifying pro-adjectives.

Comment: I do not see so as a pro adjective; I see the word as a pro form, substituting an affirmative statement.

Answer (score 0):

The only pro adjective I can come up with is such.  For example, Mr. Williams is a dedicated employee, which jobs need SUCH people working for them.

In this sentence, such serves as a pro form or pro adjective, substituting the adjective dedicated.

Actually, that is the only word I can think of as a pro adjective.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You edited the wrong answer by mistake. Please [edit] this one, which isn't deleted.